# Skip linebreak, lowercase and uppercase in sorted() function in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list which needs to be alphabetized(ignoring lower and uppercase) and printed with spaces and "+" seperating each element in the list. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2

fruit = ['A', 'banana', 'Watermelon', 'mango'] #list containing fruits name

for diet in sorted(fruit):
    print(diet)
```

This prints the each fruits in a single line. I want my result to be like this:

```
A + banana + mango + Watermelon
```

How do I achieve this result? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like we have converged on a single solution for this problem.

Comment: what does "skip linebreak" mean in title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [10]: fruit = ['A', 'banana', 'Watermelon', 'mango']

In [11]: ' + '.join(sorted(fruit, key=str.lower))
Out[11]: 'A + banana + mango + Watermelon'
```

for more detials visit :

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Answer (score 3):

```
print(" + ".join(sorted(fruit, key=str.lower)))
```